# Copy data from one column, paste in first empty column

Tags: excel, copy-paste, vba

I have data in COLUMN H2. . I want to copy them somewhere else on the same spreadsheet.
But where I copy it will change one COLUMN at a time, as each column below gets filled, by the macro.

My existing macro successfully searches for, and pastes this column of data into an empty column below, such as B31. When I have 10 new pieces of data, the next time I run the macro, I want it to paste it into C31, in Column C (being the next empty row) The next time, D31.......etc.. My macro repeatedly grabs the data in H2:H11 and pastes it into B31, but overwrites that column each time I run the macro again. It is not "seeing" column B already having data placed there by running the macro before.... What is wrong with the code?

```
Range("H2:H11").Select Selection.Copy
Range("A31").Select
Range("A31:M31").End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveCell.Rows("1:10").EntireRow.Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: Is there any data in B31 after the first Pass?

Comment: I have an alternative solution that I can post if you want.

Comment: Yes, B31 keeps getting new data put in it, overwriting previous data. FYI, A31 contains the "header" info, so it starts at a31, sees it isn't blank, moves over one cell and pastes, even when it is not blank.. post alternate solution too!

Comment: Try    Range("M31").End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Select , if that doesn't work I'm not sure why your code doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Range("A31:M31").End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Select
```

should be

```
Range("M31").End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Select
```

Alternative solution is below (i've not tested it, as i'm not on my MS PC, sorry)

```
dim lRow as Long  'Output Row
lRow = 31         'Start at row 31

    For i = 2 to 13 'Column B to Column M

         'Count if there is any values in the columns 
         '(if there is a header then change the 0 to 1)

        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ActiveSheet.Columns(i)) = 0 Then

            For Each c in Range("H2:H11")  'Cycle through output values

            ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, i).value = c.Value  'Assign values

            lRow = lRow + 1   'Increment row number

            next c

        exit for   'exit column loop

        end if

    next i
```

Comment: My method probably isn't the best way of doing things, but I try to avoid copy and pasting in macros whenever I can.

Comment: The short, one line solution fixed it... Greatly appreciated.